# Wordpress post and pages 404?

Tags: php, html, wordpress

I transfered my website on new server and new domain. I changed domain inside dashboard, exported database and imported it on new server. I also copied all of the files via ftp. New site is running good besides posts and pages. When I open page or post, I get 404 error. Also I see that many pages that I had are now missing inside Wordpress dashboard.

When I go to the phpMyAdmin I can see that all of the post are existing inside wp_posts table.

Does anyone can help with informations?

Thanks in advance,

Josip

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Looks like you are missing the .htaccess file or mod_rewrite is not enabled.  Are you using a permalink structure?  What is happening is the fancy url `http://somedomain.com/some-post-name` isn't being passed along to the bootstrap `index.php` file.

Answer (score 2):

http://interconnectit.com/124/search-and-replace-for-wordpress-databases/ the paths for the posts are absolute paths and stored as serialized data in the database. Please read this link to learn how to safely migrate to new domain/server.

Answer (score 1):

I don't have the rep to comment, so I have to answer.

Try this plugin to fix the links: **velvet-blues-update-urls**.